# Calculate income sums based on different conditions for two types of people in a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I need to create a stored procedure that returns a data set with two columns `Column1` and `Column2` primarily referring to a type of person. The stored procedure should calculate 6 rows, one for each condition that can occur within a `Table1` table, which has an FK Id that refers to either `Column1` or `Column2` based on the `Id` value.

The conditions relate to the status that person can have, defined by each row within the table (e.g., `if PersonState=1 or HealthState=2`, the states are in FK on separate tables). Therefore, for each condition specified by me and for each type of Id (i.e., column 1 and 2), I need to calculate the sum of that person's income (defined in Table1) and save it in a record. In essence, I need one row for each condition and the sum for each type of person. Can you help me?

Person data:

| IdPersonState(int) | IdHealthState(int) | IdPersonType(int) | Income(int) | Age(int) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 20000 | 21 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 10000 | 18 |
| 1 | 2 | 2 | 10000 | 14 |
| 1 | 2 | 2 | 100000 | 19 |

**Conditions**:

- Condition 1: `Age > 20`
- Condition 2: `Age <= 20 and Age > 15`
- Condition 3: `Age >= 18 OR IdPersonState = 1`

Expected result:

| Condition(just for know which condition) | Type1(name of IdPersonType) | Type2(name of IdPersonType) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Condition 1 | 20000 | 0 |
| Condition 2 | 10000 | 100000 |
| Condition 3 | 30000 | 110000 |

For example, for the all person with type=1 and with an Age > 20 the income Is 20000. For the all person with type=1 and Age > 15 and Age < 20 the income Is 10000. So even if the condition Is not supplied, the sum would be 0.

I tried to implement a stored procedure with many CASE WHEN expressions, but it seems incorrect, inelegant and difficult to read:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetIncomeByTypeAndCondition
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT
        SUM(CASE WHEN p.IdPersonType = 1 AND p.Age > 20 THEN p.Income ELSE 0 END) AS Type1,
        SUM(CASE WHEN p.IdPersonType = 2 AND p.Age > 20 THEN p.Income ELSE 0 END) AS Type2
    FROM 
        Table1 t
    INNER JOIN 
        PersonData p ON t.Id = p.IdPersonState OR t.Id = p.IdHealthState
    WHERE 
        t.Condition IN (1, 2)
    GROUP BY 
        p.IdPersonType
END
```

Comment: FWIW "stored procedure that returns a table" sql returns data sets not tables.

Comment: Keep adding data; you reference "income" and have what MIGHT   be some in the example output but none in the sample data.

Comment: Are you likely to have a single condition on multiple columns? And would they always be `AND`, or possibly `OR` and `NOT`, what about brackets?

Comment: And how many different conditions? Variable number or fixed? If variable do you want a variable number of columns, or just show null in the extra columns? What are the datatypes of the columns (please show full table schema)?

Comment: @Charlieface now i hope you understand

Comment: You have an upvote - that's certainly not criticism

Comment: Thank you for your help, instead of answer a question, you criticize me. I have joined Yesterday on stackoverflow. Thanks

Comment: Where is this criticism you keep talking about? I can only see people trying to help .

Comment: You help me with answering the question?

Answer (score 1):

Although there are ways to do this in a single query (using a bunch of `CASE` conditions) I would venture to say its probably not very efficient.

Instead you can use dynamic SQL. But to prevent injection problems I would say you are best off ensuring that Table1 is well defined and can be checked.

```sql
CREATE TABLE Table1 (
  Id int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY CHECK (Id <= 10),
  ConditionGroup varchar(50) NOT NULL
  ColumnName sysname NOT NULL,
  Compare varchar(2) NOT NULL CHECK (Compare IN ('=', '<>', '<', '<=', '>', '>=')),
  Value int NOT NULL,
  JoinOp varchar(3) NOT NULL CHECK (JoinOp IN ('AND', 'OR'))
);
```

Then you can generate a dynamic SQL statement that unions the result of queries for each separate condition.

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE GetIncomeByTypeAndCondition
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table1) > 10
    THROW 50001, 'Too many conditions', 1;

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);

SELECT @sql = STRING_AGG(CAST(ConditionSql AS nvarchar(max)), '
UNION ALL
')
FROM (
    SELECT
      t1.ConditionGroup,

      ConditionSql = '
SELECT
  Condition = ' + QUOTENAME(t1.ConditionGroup, '''') + ',
  SUM(CASE WHEN p.IdPersonType = 1 THEN p.Income ELSE 0 END) AS Type1,
  SUM(CASE WHEN p.IdPersonType = 2 THEN p.Income ELSE 0 END) AS Type2
FROM dbo.PersonData p
WHERE 1=1 ' + STRING_AGG(p.JoinOp + '
  p.' + QUOTENAME(c.name) + t1.Compare + ' @p' + p.Id

      , '')
    FROM sys.columns c
    JOIN sys.tables t ON to.object_id = c.object_id AND t.name = 'PersonData'
    JOIN sys.schemas s ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id AND s.name = 'dbo'
    JOIN Table1 t1 ON t1.ColumnName = c.name
    GROUP BY
      t1.ConditionGroup
) conditions;

DECLARE
  @p1 int, @p2 int, @p3 int, @p4 int, @p5 int, @p6 int, @p7 int, @p8 int, @p9 int, @p10 int;

SELECT
  @p1 = MIN(CASE WHEN Id = 1 THEN Value END),
  @p2 = MIN(CASE WHEN Id = 2 THEN Value END),
  @p3 = MIN(CASE WHEN Id = 3 THEN Value END),
  @p4 = MIN(CASE WHEN Id = 4 THEN Value END),
  @p5 = MIN(CASE WHEN Id = 5 THEN Value END),
  @p6 = MIN(CASE WHEN Id = 6 THEN Value END),
  @p7 = MIN(CASE WHEN Id = 7 THEN Value END),
  @p8 = MIN(CASE WHEN Id = 8 THEN Value END),
  @p9 = MIN(CASE WHEN Id = 9 THEN Value END),
  @p10 = MIN(CASE WHEN Id = 10 THEN Value END);
FROM Table1;

PRINT @sql; -- your friend

EXEC sp_executesql
  @sql,
  N'@p1 int, @p2 int, @p3 int, @p4 int, @p5 int, @p6 int, @p7 int, @p8 int, @p9 int, @p10 int,
  @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6, @p7, @p8, @p9, @p10;
```

If you need more than 10 parameters then adjust as necessary.

---

You can even make `Table1` a table valued parameter rather than a fixed table, for example:

```sql
CREATE TYPE dbo.Condition (
  Id int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY CHECK (Id <= 10),
  ConditionGroup varchar(50) NOT NULL
  ColumnName sysname NOT NULL,
  Compare varchar(2) NOT NULL CHECK (Compare IN ('=', '<>', '<', '<=', '>', '>=')),
  Value int NOT NULL,
  JoinOp varchar(3) NOT NULL CHECK (JoinOp IN ('AND', 'OR'))
);
```

---

Having said all this, it's usually **much easier** to do this from a client application, such as C# or Python.

Comment: the conditions are not a SQL condition but always boolean, and the result set have to be group by every condition

Comment: So, i can use both stored procedure and C# code because the application is related to ASP.NET Core MVC. but i have necessarly to use a stored procedure to calculate the values. It is necessary for me, after the calculation of the result set, in a future, to historicize that values, anytime it was requested

Comment: in addition to that, the conditions are not passed in input